# Dynamic Programming - Number of combinations to reach a given target

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

This is a basic dynamic programming problem - Number of score combinations. I am aware of the bottom up approach for this problem which works well.

However, I am unable to work towards finding a top-down solution approach for the problem. Caching the recursive part gives us more than necessary combinations(where ordering/sequence of scores is also a factor, so, to avoid it we need to provide a constraint to make the sequence increase monotonically. Here is recursive approach for the same. [Dynamic Programming - Number of distinct combinations to reach a given score](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37850116/dynamic-programming-number-of-distinct-combinations-to-reach-a-given-score)

Here is my current code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int helper(int target, vector<int>& coins, vector<int>& cache, int min) {
    if(target < 0) return 0;
    if(target == 0) return 1;
    if(cache[target] != 0) return cache[target];

    for(auto& c : coins) {
        if(target >= c && min <= c) {
            //cout << min << " " << c << " " << target << endl;
            cache[target] += helper(target-c, coins, cache, c) ;
            //cout << cache[target] << endl;            
        }

    }

    return cache[target];

}


int main() {

    vector<int> coins{2, 3};

    int target = 7;
    vector<int> cache(target+1, 0);
    cache[0] = 1;
    cache [7] = helper(target, coins, cache, 1);

    for (auto& x : cache) cout << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Here](https://ideone.com/XXBKqh) is  run-able ideone link.

Comment: can you share your bottom-up approach also?

Comment: @PhamTrung, here is the bottom-up approach - https://ideone.com/wB3kr3 . This is for the case where sequence/ordering of scores is not a factor.

Comment: I dont understand what are you trying to calculate

Comment: @juvian, this is a standard dynamic programming problem - Number of Score combinations - we need to count the number of various of combinations by which we can attain a given target - you can read more about it here - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-number-ways-reach-given-score-game/

Comment: so this? https://ideone.com/tAxgtv

Comment: @DiwakarMoturu why do you initialize `cache[0]` to 1 ? it is impossible to express 0 by coins 2 or 3, so `cache[0]` should be 0

Comment: @juvian, your code works, but it is bottom-up, solution is constructed from target = 1 and then eventually goes to required target, and then terminates. Top-down approach goes the other way, like recursion does.

Comment: @mangusta, this is the base case, we can express 0 by null set. Other way to look at it is, if we reach a target zero, that implies we found a combination of coins. so we add 1 to number of combinations for that target.

Comment: You need to incorporate `min` into the cache key, since it affects the cached result.

Comment: @DiwakarMoturu `target=0` and `cache[0]` are different things

Comment: @mangusta, indices of the cache are values of target. So cache[0] is target = 0.

Comment: @MattTimmermans, yeah, I am not exactly sure how to do it. Another SO thread I linked here did some thing of that sort. But makes the space complexity no less than matrix (coins x target). The reason using 1D vector is so that we can reduce the cache space.

Comment: if you want a top down approach you need to store both target and min, no way around it unless you dont care about recalculating known values